# sqlite with hibernate and spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sqlite

I have a problem with sqlite3, hibernate and spring.In fact, if I start the program and call the createType () method that creates a type and after that I call the getAllTypes () method I have the values ​​of the object I just created appear in the browser.But if I check with a "select * from type" in my table type to see if the object was added in my table, I have no record. In addition, as soon as I restart the program and I call the method getAllTypes () to view the data of my table I have nothing that appears in my browser.Again, for each startup looks like the ID is reset since it starts at 1 (for example if after starting my program I try to insert 2 objects with the method createType () I have: ID = 1 and ID = 2 which appears in my browser). So if my data is not saved in my table where have they been? I made 2 recordings manually in my table and I also can not get these 2 records with the methods getAllTypes () which is supposed to send me all the records of my table. I'm told that there may be a communication problem between my program and my database.Thank you in advance for your help!!!

This is how I call my methods in browsers:

> http://localhost:8080/types/getAllTypes
>   http://localhost:8080/types/insert

application.yml

```
spring: 
 profile:dev 
jpa:
 hibernate:
  hbm2ddl.auto:update
 properties:
  hibernate:
   dialect:org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
 datasource:
  url:jdbc:sqlite:C:\Users\user pc\Desktop\PDF\testrest.db
  username:user
  password:password
  driverClassName:org.sqlite.JDBC
```

My dependency in my pom.xml for the configuration of sqlite,hibernate and spring :

```
    <parent> 
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
   </parent>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.zsoltfabok</groupId>
          <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
          <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.196</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
         <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId> 
       </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
         <version>4.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
         <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.3.0</version>
      <dependency>
```

My table type:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS type(
  idType integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  description varchar(256) NOT NULL
)
```

My entities type:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="typedifficulte")
public class Type {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long idType;
    private String description;
    public Type() {

    }

    public Type(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public long getIdType() {
        return idType;
    }
    public void setIdType(long idType) {
        this.idType = idType;
    }
}
```

My interface TypeService :

```
public interface TypeService {
    Collection<Type>  getAllTypes();
    Type createType(Type type);
}
```

My TypeServiceImpl :

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.apache.commons.collections4.IteratorUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service(value="typeService")
public class TypeServiceImpl implements TypeService {

    @Resource
    private TypeRepository typeRepository;

    @Override
    public Collection<Type> getAllTypes() {
        return  IteratorUtils.toList(this.typeRepository.findAll().iterator());
    }

    @Override
    public Type createType(Type type) {
        return this.typeRepository.save(type);
    }

    public TypeRepository getTypeRepository() {
        return typeRepository;
    }

    public void setTypeRepository(TypeRepository typeRepository) {
        this.typeRepository = typeRepository;   
    }
}
```

My TypeRepository :

```
public interface TypeRepository extends CrudRepository<Type,Long> {
    Type findByDescription(String description);
}
```

My Controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value ="/types")
public class TypeController {

    @Resource
    private TypeService typeService;

    @RequestMapping(value= "/getAllTypes", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Collection<Type> getAllTypes() {
        return this.typeService.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/insert",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Type createType() {
        return this.typeService.createType(new Type("test"));
    }
}
```

And finally my startup class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class MainLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainLauncher.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried using `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` instead of `spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` ?

Comment: Yes I used it but it changes nothing.